# Problemas con AJAX jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente ajax y quiero mandar a "datos.php" los datos que tiene mi objeto `obj` pero lo no lo hace y me manda el alert("No se pueden recuperar los datos...");

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'http://nombre_server/datos.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: obj,
       success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
               alert(data);
       },
       error: function(data) {
              alert("No se pueden recuperar los datos...");
       }
});
```

el objeto `obj` lo formo de la siguiente manera

```
$("#lista div input, #lista div select").each(function(i,e){
                    obj.push({
                        id:$(this).attr("id"),
                        valor:$(this).val()
                    });
                });
                console.log(obj);
```

e imprimiendo el obj en consola lo muestra de la siguiente manera

```
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
id
:
"0"
valor
:
"true"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
id
:
"1"
valor
:
"echo"
```

y en el archivo datos.php me muestra

```
undefined:
undefined:
undefined:
undefined: //son 10 undefined en total
```

el problema es que no se por que...
no se que este mal alguien que me pueda ayudar

Comment: haz probado quitar comillas simples y poner comillas normales

Comment: ¿Quieres enviar una serie de valores que están en un elemento `select`?

Comment: no @Jorius  quiero enviar los datos que tiene mi `obj`

Comment: Así es @LuisFernando pero igual me da el mismo error

Comment: -1, no está para nada claro que es lo que quieres, con el each expresas que quieres almacenar el id y el valor de todos los option en un select y creo que ahí está el error

Comment: Al parecer quieres crear un objeto con todos los valores de ciertos inputs y de ciertos select. ¿Lo que se imprime en el `console.log` contiene los datos de esos inputs y de esos select? Ten en cuenta que el error podría estar en tu archivo `datos.php`, sería útil que muestres su código. Aparte de eso, usas código obsoleto `success... error` y no indicas el `datatype` de la llamada Ajax.

Comment: He probado el código jQuery y me funciona, es decir, la petición Ajax es enviada con éxito al servidor y obtengo la respuesta del archivo php. Casi seguro que tienes un error en `datos.php`.

Comment: @Soldier si puedes muestra como recibes los datos en tu archivo `datos.php`

Comment: Como dice @Soldier el problema puede ser del lado del servidor, su usas un json_decode para procesar los datos deberías enviarlos como data: JSON.stringify(obj) por dar un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Usa en el `$.ajax`:

```
data: {'data': obj}
```

y recupera los datos como `$_POST['data']`

Para enviar un object en el ajax, pero no podrías recuperarlos en PHP:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi amigo el problema radica en que debes prestar mas atención como funciona el ajax de jquery la data se enviá un json que es un array constituido por propiedad:valor es decir que nosotros mandamos una el nombre con el que sera recibido en el controlador o archivo que procese los archivos

tú mi amigo lo que estas haciendo es pasar un array de objetos ARRAY! mas no un JSON que diga la propiedad:valor.

un array lleva las pocisiones [0],[1],[2] que estas en tu código están siendo enviadas en un array de tipo JSON.

espero haberme explicado si tu lo que quieres es enviar algo a través de AJAX asegurate que le envíes un JSON por medio de tu httpRequest es decir mandar solamente el JSON mas no un array de tipo JSON

lo que personalmente te sugiero es crear una cadena que separes por un | es decir id|valor por ejemplo creo una cadena :

`var  string = $(this).attr('id')+"|"+$(this).val()`

y esa agregarla a un array llamado "miarray" entonces:

```
miarray.push(string);
```

despues añadir ese array de strings en el data  de la siguiente manera:

```
datos={'items[]':myarray};
```

finalmente enviar datos en tu ajax asi:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'mipagina.php',
    data:datos,
    method:'post',
    success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
   },
   error: function(data) {
          alert("No se pueden recuperar los datos...");
   }});
```

y recibes en php con :

```
$POST_REQUEST['items[]'];
```

ya nadamas iteras el array de nuevo y lo separas con str_split o explode() en php espero te sirva saludos!!!